# restart count in php for each item

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, count

I need the code to restart count for each $item

My code is:

```
 $count = 0;
 $folders = @scandir('Users/');  
 foreach($folders as $item){
   if (preg_match("/.*\.php$/",$item)) continue;
   echo $item;
   if (is_dir("Users/$item")){
     $target_folders = @scandir("Users/$item/uploaded/");
     foreach($target_folders as $target_item){
       if ((!preg_match("/^[.]/",$item)) ||(!is_dir("Users/$item/uploaded/$target_item"))) $count++;
     }
   }
 }
```

if this can be done the help would be much appreciated. this is the last little bit on my project.

Comment: `foreach($folders as $item){ $count = 0; ... `?

Comment: As u_mulder mentions can you just move the `$count=0` inside the `foreach`?

Comment: can you post it as answer so i can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$count_result=array();
$path = "Users";
$folders = @scandir("$path");
if ($folders) {
    foreach ($folders as $item) {
        $count = 0;
        if ((substr($item, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $item)))
            continue;

        if (is_dir($path . "/" . $item)) {
            echo "$item<br>";


            $target_folders = @scandir($path . "/" . $item . "/uploaded/");
            if ($target_folders) {
                foreach ($target_folders as $target_item) {
                    if ((substr($target_item, 0, 1) == '.') || is_dir("$path/$item/uploaded/$target_item"))
                        continue;
                    $count++;

                }
            }
            $count_result[$item]=$count;

        }
    }
}

var_dump($count_result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the $count variable equal to zero inside the first foreach loop ( as u_mulder suggested )

```
$count = 0;
$folders = @scandir('Users/');

foreach($folders as $item){

      $count = 0;
      if (preg_match("/.*\.php$/",$item)) 
           continue;

      echo $item;

      if (is_dir("Users/$item")){

           $target_folders = @scandir("Users/$item/uploaded/");
           foreach($target_folders as $target_item){

                if ((!preg_match("/^[.]/",$item)) || (!is_dir("Users/$item/uploaded/$target_item")))
                     $count++;

           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Put `;` after `$count = 0`.

Comment: ok now i just need to get rid of the dots and the $item value in the array for it to count correctly